# How to create a dual boot in SSD in which Ubuntu is already installed

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, windows-10, boot-partition

[result of df -h|grep sd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGdle.png)[result of sudo parted -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AmqA.png) I have a 240 GB SSD in which I have already installed Ubuntu. But now I have to dual boot with Windows10. But I'm unable to create a partition.

Comment: What brand/model system? UEFI or BIOS install of Ubuntu. Post this, above in your question to preserve formatting: `sudo parted -l` Best to only use UEFI. And Windows in UEFI mode wants multiple partitions. Similar question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308295/how-can-i-install-windows-10-20h2-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: What does the output of test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios show? Also useful to post up output of `df -h|grep sd`. – Paul Benson 11 mins ago

Comment: Output of test -d .... is EFI also check screenshot added in question. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) and [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6317/)