# How can I install Windows 10 (20H2) after I've installed Ubuntu? [Legacy BIOS only]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-10

I am currently on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and I want to install windows 10 without removing my ubuntu.
I want to install win10 on my real PC not virtualbox.

How can I do it?

Will win10 cause problem with grub boot loader?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? UEFI or BIOS install of Ubuntu? Is drive gpt partitioned? BIOS/MBR  mode will cause major issues, Windows often deletes Linux partitions, but UEFI/gpt usually works. But always have good backups. What brand/model system? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations last install makes itself first in boot order, so if you want Ubuntu, you have to change that.

Comment: BIOS. Dell Vostro 3450.

Comment: Then Windows only installs in primary NTFS partition with boot flag with MBR. Normal install is two primary partitions, one boot and one main or your c: "drive" partition. But it can be installed into one primary partition.

Comment: that question is for UEFI system.

Comment: No, that question is for legacy/BIOS, like your's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: make a ntfs partition from gparted or gnome disk.

Step 2: create a bootable usb drive containing windows 10

Step 3: Install windows on that ntfs partition

Step 4: Create a bootable usb containing ubuntu

Step 5: Boot-up using the usb with ubuntu but don't install ubuntu

step 6: To install boot repair open terminal and enter these commands::

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

step 7: Open boot repair and select recommended repair. It will reinstall grub bootloader

Step 8:Reboot after the repair is done.